# How to ignore specific folders from Picasa

Tags: picasa

I shoot using my DSLR with RAW+JPG setting, which means all my pictures are duplicated into Picasa. I usually import everything and then move all the `.CR2` files into a subfolder called `RAW`.

How can I prevent these file from being displayed into Picasa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about Windows, but prefixing the folder name with `.` did the trick for me: the filesystem (and possibly Picasa) handle this as a hidden folder, and it will not be displayed or scanned in Picasa, even if it's in a subfolder of a watched folder.

For example, the naming the folder `.RAW` hide the `.CR2` files from Picasa.

Answer (score 2):

Try Tools > Folder Manager. Select the folder you want to exclude, and click 'Remove from Picasa'.